# Capture a command's stderr in a variable if it fails

Tags: bash

How can I run a command in a bash script and while it's running, print its output (in this case the command is `wget`, which prints output for its runtime), but if the command fails, save the error (stderr) into a variable?

This is the command I use:

```
wget --user=$FTP_USER --password=$FTP_PASSWORD ftp://$FTP_URL
```

Answer (score 3):

I'd capture stderr in a variable in all cases, but only use it when the command fails.

```
if ! { error=$(your_command 2>&1 >&3); } 3>&1; then
  # do something with $error
fi
```

Comment: Thanks, but in this solution the command output if it succeeded does not appear while executing the command, but only after it is executed. I want the output to show in the meantime, and only if an error has occurred - save it to the variable (in wget command there is a progress bar output during the execution of the command).

Comment: @TGB Works fine here. If you provide a [mre] I'll take a look

Answer (score 1):

Just save stderr to a variable.

```
{ err=$(wget ... 2>&1 1>&3); } 3>&1
```